# AngularJS ng-repeat doesn't detected dynamically generated array using ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

### Problem

I'm finding ng-repeat directive isn't able to track the addition of a new array.
In my example the new array is 'options'.
The directive is part of a template being displayed using ng-dialog (3rd party lib).
If i close the dialogbox and open it again the ng-repeat will pick up those changes I made before closing it.

I've tried $scope.$apply();  But I get a warning that it is already running.

### Update ++

The solution I ended up using was adding a function on the ng-init to check the existence of that array first, if it didn't exist it created it and then assigned it to the new variable.

Here is a more in depth example,
Writing this jsFiddle has pointed out the issue is within the ng-include/ng-repeat - without this it is fine.
<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/20mobk2h/56/</strike>
http://jsfiddle.net/20mobk2h/61/

The ng-repeat loops on an array called options that may or may not exist.

```
<div ng-init="options = element.options">
    <div ng-repeat="option in options" ng-include="'optionsTree'"></div>
</div>
```

I add a new option by:

```
$scope.addItem = function(item) {

    if(!item.options){
        item.options = [];
    }

    var obj = {
        val: 'blah'
    };

    item.options.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Scope issue. Post demo maybe?

Comment: Im working on a jsFiddle atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code:

```
<div ng-init="options = item.options">
    <div ng-repeat="option in options" ng-include="'nest_options'"></div>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="option in item.options" ng-include="'nest_options'"></div>
</div>
```

The problem here is that when you assign `item.options` to new variable `options` you break reference with `item` object, because for the first time (when `item.options` is `undefined`) options is `undefined` and primitive values are passed by value in Javascript. So later when you change `options` property (by adding new array element) this change is not reflected in `options` variable.

However when you open popup for the second time, `item.options` is no longer `undefined`, it's already an object (array), so assignment `options = item.options` results into normal object reference, and changes to `item.options` are mirrored in `item`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/20mobk2h/57/

Comment: Hey this is very close and I do agree with your change. However (as bad as i am at writing SO questions - I missed something out that might have been important as to why i do what i do http://jsfiddle.net/20mobk2h/61/   - I need to rename them so i can then add a new array to the last array, and can pass the same named vars ( check the template html )

Comment: Your point was spot on the issue, I didnt use this answer directly but it indirectly gave me the solution - on init = generate the array if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I also wanted to suggest this, so that `options` always defined and never primitive. Anyway, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.$apply()` should really be the solution to your problem.

Try using this wrapper to `$scope.$apply()`

```
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
  var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
  if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
    if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
      fn();
    }
  } else {
    this.$apply(fn);
  }
};
```

And then just replace $apply with safeApply wherever you need it

```
$scope.safeApply(function() {
  alert('Now I'm wrapped for protection!');
});
```

Probably passing it the function you need running. Using this you should be able to respect the apply - digest cycle and run the `apply` only when it is allowed.

Taken from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma)

Answer (score 0):

could you write full code of your controller and the page ? 
Have you specified ng-controller in yr page and routeProvider both ? Remove ng-controller from page if its specified in routeProvider.